# How do I reference Powerpoints default user template path?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In Word you can reference the default users templates path using :

```
strFolder = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdUserTemplatesPath)
```

In Excel you can reference the default users template path using :

```
strFolder = Application.TemplatesPath
```

---

For Powerpoint, I currently use :

```
strFolder = Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates"
```

**But this is hard coded and will fail if the user has their templates in another location.**

Would be nice if this common function had common syntax across the MSOffice applications.

How would I create a more robust method of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good idea to mention the specific version of Office you're working with and in cases like this where there's nothing exposed to the object model, explain HOW the user has set the thing you're looking to reveal.

In some versions of PPT (more recent ones) File | Options | Save | Default personal templates location allows user to choose a location for their personal templates.  When they enter a path there, it's stored in the registry; for PPT 2016, it's in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\PowerPoint\Options
PersonalTemplates 
Reg_Expand_Sz
The path the user typed
```

For regular (ie, not personal) templates, I think it's a group policy setting.
This might be a good place to look for documentation:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030